# how to push using only ssh-key on vps repository [git bash]

Tags: windows, git-bash, vps

I am novice, but I learn fast. I try to push to a vps using only ssh-keys in git bash on windows 10.

Problem is that, I do not know how to tell to git bash to use ssh-keys only and stop asking the password when it comes to looging and push.

I inserted the same public key in the repository /home/git/project and in the user .ssh authorized keys.
Can someone guide me on this procedure?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No problem anymore.
Just need to add ssh keys in user folder and use tortoise + putty pageant to authenticate for push/pull.

No answer from the community but it is ok.